# Multiple INNER JOINS very slow - Is there a better way?

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization

I'm struggling with the Query below.
It's really slow and I can't figure out how to make it more effective?

```
    SELECT * FROM cBookings 
                INNER JOIN cBookings_details ON cBookings.cBookings_id=cBookings_details_cBookings_id 
                INNER JOIN cCustomers ON cBookings.cBookings_cCustomers_id=cCustomers.cCustomers_id 
                INNER JOIN cObjects ON cBookings_details.cBookings_details_cObjects_id = cObjects.cObjects_id
                WHERE cBookings_details.cBookings_details_cObjects_id = '".$oid."' 
                AND cBookings_details.cBookings_details_arrival <= '".$firstday."' 
                AND cBookings_details.cBookings_details_departure >= '".$firstday."' 
                GROUP BY(cBookings_details.cBookings_details_cObjects_id)
```

Explain information: [image]

Comment: Use `explain` to find out where you need an index.

Comment: @Jens I'm unfamiliar with 'explain' - How would you suggest i approached that?

Comment: run the query with explain in the front of it and post the result here

Comment: explain select.....
but you need indices on all columns used in a join and in the group by, otherwise performance can suffer greatly. Don't even bother doing an explain before you have made sure you have all the necessary indices.

Comment: @AdrianBR That's putting the cart before the horse.

Comment: @Martin Why are you using GROUP BY here? And do you really have a column called `cBookings_details_cBookings_id`. Oh wait, this is an insane naming policy; I'm not even going to try to solve this one. That way, madness lies.

Comment: @Strawberry Maybee i could change the GROUP-statement to distinct? Its to rule out duplicates. cBookings_details_cBookings_id is refering to parent booking (cBookings_id)

Comment: In principle, you should never use a GROUP BY clause where a DISTINCT operation is intended. The unfortunate aspect of this prinicple is that GROUP BY *is* faster - but it's also extremely like to return erroneous or unexpected results - especially on more complex queries.

Comment: @Strawberry Ok, I'll think about that. However, do you have any other thoughts regarding speeding up the Query, rather than making it even slower? :-)

Comment: You performed what would be called in other sqls an 'illegal group operation', meaning you retrieved several non-aggregated columns but only grouped on one- The others will have random content from any of the rows from the same group (same grouped column/s value)

Comment: But back to the topic of slowness, index the join columns. currently there are no usable indices for your joins. You are not putting the cart before the horse, you are just putting the cart together. Joins without indices will always be expensive, and ram is cheaper than what it used to be 15 years ago. As unnecessary as it may be, you could potentially fully index almost any database nowadays, as ram is cheap and plentiful, while working hours spent on optimisation are not.

Comment: @AdrianBR RAM might be cheap, but it still takes a hit on INSERTs, UPDATEs, etc. More indexes equals slower DMLs.

Comment: The `EXPLAIN` says Rows=1 for each item.  Can't get better than that.  So, I am suspicious that that Explain is not for the query in question.

Comment: If you want to use `GROUP BY` then follow with `ORDER BY NULL `. Else it will use filesort to filter the details. Please check whether we have any criteria to avoid group by. Don't use `SELECT *`. Select only the necessary columns. Columns with `Character` may slowness your query.